# How to set defaut value for a many2one field in Odoo 9.0c?

Tags: forms, odoo-9, many-to-one

I have customized a module that include a many2one field. Now, I would like to set the default value for that field with the codition is: [[u'bom_ids', u'!=', False]]. i have tried below code but it did not work probebly

```
width_id = field.Many2one('sale.order.line.width', default ='_get_width_default')

def _get_width_default(self, cr, uid, context=None): 
     res = self.pool.get('product.template').search(cr, uid, [(u'bom_ids', u'!=', False)], context=context)
     return res and res[0] or False


default = {
'width_id' : _get_width_default,
}
```

Could you guy please help me to point what is the problem and how to sovle the problem and finnally get my purpose. Thank for watching

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _get_width_default(self, cr, uid, context=None): 
    #REPLACE DOMAIN WITH SOMETHING RELEVANT
    domain = []
    res = self.pool.get('sale.order.line.width').search(cr, uid, domain, context=context)
    _logger.info("PREPARING DEFAULT VALUE")
    _logger.info(res)
    return res[0] or False

width_id = fields.many2one('sale.order.line.width')

_defaults = {
    'width_id' : _get_width_default,
}
```

What do you see as far as logging is concerned? Try the above code (v7 style).

Odoo9 Style (NEW API)

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _get_width_default(self): 
    #REPLACE DOMAIN WITH SOMETHING RELEVANT
    domain = []
    res = self.env['sale.order.line.width'].search(domain)
    _logger.info("PREPARING DEFAULT VALUE")
    _logger.info(res)
    return res[0].id or False

width_id = fields.many2one('sale.order.line.width',default=_get_width_default)
```

Comment: thank you for replying me. i will try thr code first and write the feedback as long as i get the réult

Comment: Hello Mr Phillip Stack, maybe my system has some thing wrong, it does not change any thing after i recode the .py field, it still work acctually the same like when i set the default = '1'. do you have any idea?

Comment: Need i make any change with the view form?

Comment: I will take a look when I get into the office. If you see no logging then I would assume the function is not getting called at all. I will have to find an example of v7 api default many2one

Comment: I have amended my suggestion

Comment: I think another potential issue is that your related field is of model 'sale.order.line.width' and in your function you were assigning it an id from the 'product.template' model. When assigning values on a many2one the record should belong to the model you have defined for that related field.

Comment: I will recode the funcsion following your helps, but i cannot forget to say thanks to you, have a nice day Sr.

Comment: So I need to add an related filed in the model in model :'sale.order.line.width', in that related filed i need to get the funscion to get the product_ids from product id that match the condision: (u'bom_ids', u'!=', False). Moreover, my purepose is when making new sale order, when i choose anyproducts that have been set the Bill of masterial the system will automatically call the funcsion that get back the default value of many2one filed, if the product have not been set the BOMaterial, then the funscion will get Fale.